# Is it meaningful to execute "make modules_install" without executing "make modules"?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, makefile, kernel

From [KernelBuild](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild) tutorial from http://kernelnewbies.org, I don't see "`make modules`" command. This article only executes "`make`" command before "`sudo make modules_install install`".

But from `make help` output:

```
  all             - Build all targets marked with [*]
* vmlinux         - Build the bare kernel
* modules         - Build all modules
  modules_install - Install all modules to INSTALL_MOD_PATH (default: /)
```

It seems that without "`make modules`" command, there is no need to execute "`make modules_install`" command. Is it meaningful to execute "`make modules_install`" without executing "`make modules`"?

Comment: When that tutorial tells you to do `make` without a target, the default target `all` is selected.  `make all` builds modules (as indicated by the `*` in the help text you quoted), so after that you are ready for `make modules_install`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it meaningful to execute “make modules_install” without executing “make modules”?

Yes, but only if you have already executed `make` before the `make modules_install`. You can't execute `modules_install` if modules weren't built with the `make modules` or just `make`. There is only one difference between `make` and `make modules`: the `make modules` compiles only modules or source code which is set as

```
obj-CONFIG_OPTION_NAME=m
```

in the Makefile. If you want just to build Linux kernel, just use `make`, the `make modules` already included there.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you understand the procedure correctly.

*make modules* 
This will just compile all modules just like any other program. Creating object files.

*make modules_install* 
 Once your files are compiled without any error then this command will put generated .so files to the appropriate directories.

So if you run modules_install without make modules then there will be nothing to copy.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Kernel modules have .ko extension and .so is used for userspace libraries